# Protecting REST interface from reverse-engineered access

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am writing an SPA (Angular) that uses a REST back-end (JSON) to access the data base.  It was fairly easy to add an OAUTH-based token-based authentication system to handle login and authorization of requests.

What now concerns me is how to detect when someone writes their own application that accesses my REST server?    What I want to do is adopt a terms of use where the server access is free if you use my SPA but charge a fee if the user is writing their own app.

It certainly wouldn't be difficult to reverse engineer the API.  Since all the SPA code is accessible to the user I can't think of a way were you couldn't write an alternative SPA that would access the server and it couldn't tell the difference.

Any pointers as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

CORS headers will prevent someone on a different domain to access your service. Just make sure you set them correctly and don't open them up to the world.

It doesn't prevent someone from proxying through your service though. That's harder to block. You could look out for heightend activity from some ip addresses.

OAuth2 can also help. It will make it at least a tad harder for someone else to pretend their a browser. This too works well because you'll see a lot of activity from different users (presumably) all coming from the same ip address, or range.

The best advice though is to create your service such that it doesn't matter if someone else consumes it. Maybe you can find a way to do the exact opposite and completely open it up. Lots of services have been successful with open apis (in fact, they can get more successful). Do you have a specific reason to not allow users to conveniently access data from your service?

Comment: what I want to do is have the API free to those who accessed through the web application I provide but I expect eventually people will want to form their own data base queries into the back end and I want to charge them for that.

Comment: @AlanObject well if that's your requirement, you just have to enforce that in your API, not in the frontend.